# SQL - Using sum but optionally using default value for row

Tags: mysql, sql

Given tables

```
asset
  col - id
date_sequence
  col - date
daily_history
  col - date
  col - num_error_seconds
  col - asset_id
historical_event
  col - start_date
  col - end_date
  col - asset_id
```

I'm trying to count up all the daily num_error_seconds for all assets in a given time range in order to display "Percentage NOT in error" by day. The catch is if there is a historical_event involving an asset that has an end_date beyond the sql query range, then daily_history should be ignored and a default value of 86400 seconds (one day of error_seconds) should be used for that asset

The query I have that does not use the historical_event is:

```
select ds.date, 
  IF(count(dh.time) = 0, 
    100, 
    100 - (100*sum(dh.num_error_seconds) / (86400 * count(*)))
  ) percent
  from date_sequence ds 
  join asset a
  left join daily_history dh on dh.date = ds.date and dh.asset_id=a.asset_id
  where ds.date >= in_start_time and ds.date <= in_end_time
  group by ds.thedate;
```

To build on this is beyond my SQL knowledge. Because of the aggregate function, I cannot simply inject 86400 seconds for each asset that is associated with an event that has an end_date beyond the in_end_time.

```
Sample Data
Asset
1
2

Date Sequence
2013-09-01
2013-09-02
2013-09-03
2013-09-04

Daily History
2013-09-01, 1400, 1
2013-09-02, 1501, 1
2013-09-03, 1420, 1
2013-09-04, 0, 1
2013-09-01, 10000, 2
2013-09-02, 20000, 2
2013-09-03, 30000, 2
2013-09-04, 40000, 2

Historical Event
start_date, end_date, asset_id
2013-09-03 12:01:03, 2014-01-01 00:00:00, 1
```

What I would expect to see with this sample data is a % of time these assets are in error

```
2013-09-01 => 100 - (100*(1400 + 10000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-02 => 100 - (100*(1501 + 20000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-03 => 100 - (100*(1420 + 30000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-04 => 100 - (100*(0 + 40000))/(86400*2)
```

Except: There was a historical event which should take precendence. It happened on 9/3 and is open-ended (has an end date in the future, so the calculations would change to:

```
2013-09-01 => 100 - (100*(1400 + 10000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-02 => 100 - (100*(1501 + 20000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-03 => 100 - (100*(86400 + 30000))/(86400*2)
2013-09-04 => 100 - (100*(86400 + 40000))/(86400*2)
```

Asset 1's num_error_seconds gets overwritten with a full day of error seconds if there is a historical event that has a start_date before 'in_end_time' and an end_time after the in_end_time

Can this be accomplished in one query? Or do I need to stage data with an initial query?

Comment: I think some sample data would help make this clear.

Comment: Good point, added sample data and more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:

```
Select
    ds.date,
    100 - 100 * Sum(
        case
            when he.asset_id is not null then 86400 -- have a historical_event
            when dh.num_error_seconds is null then 0 -- no daily_history record
            else dh.num_error_seconds
        end
    ) / 86400 / count(a.id) as percent -- need to divide by number of assets
From
    date_sequence ds
        cross join
    asset a
        left outer join
    daily_history dh 
        on a.id = dh.asset_id and
           ds.date = dh.date
        left outer join (
            select distinct -- avoid counting multiple he records
                asset_id
            from
                historical_event he
            Where
                he.end_date > in_end_time
        ) he
        on a.id = he.asset_id    
Where
    ds.date >= in_start_time and
    ds.date <= in_end_time -- I'd prefer < here
Group By
    ds.date
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b01f08/8)

Comment: Wow, sqlfiddle, that's a great tool, thanks for working that logic out. The conditional/case in the sum is exactly what I was missing, thanks. I've got a bit more work to do to add the historical_event start_date into this fiddle, but this gets me most of the way.